# Can't bypass filter

Tags: php, injection, owasp-bwa

Trying some malicious injection against bWAPP and came across bypass captcha

Filter validating captcha is

```
if($_POST["captcha_user"] == $_SESSION["captcha"])
```

Tried input  `1' || '2` but it doesn't bypass logical condition.

Comment: Hint: `==` is considered unsafe. [You'll find more information in this answer on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40392064)

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What is your question? Why do you attempt an SQL injection payload in a PHP comparison?

Comment: @Sjoerd I'm sorry. I corrected sql part. And my question is why my malicious input isn't bypassing the logical condition and executing corresponding branch

Comment: @Ryuzaki what is `$_SESSION["captcha"]` likely to be? And how can you fool the `==` comparator? Have a look at the link I handed you. Besides; it's obvious that you don't understand the task you're attempting to perform, and thus it should be closed at this SE.

Comment: @vidarlo I want to know why logical expression which I'm trying to make with malicious input (e.g. '1' || '2' =='randomcaptchstring') is evaluating to be false and stopping me from going past the filter. $_SESSION["captcha"] is any random string

Comment: Because you are not supplying something that PHP evaluates as `==` to whatever the expected captcha value is. The post I linked details how the `==` operator works. Read it. Install PHP on your computer and play with it.

Comment: So, the resulting string is: `if($_POST["1' || '2"] == $_SESSION["captcha"])` ? Can you see how that wouldn't work?

Comment: @schroeder that's probably wrong. `$_POST["captcha_user"]` is a variable in an array, so the eval becomes `"1' || '2" == "somestring"`. But `"1' || '2"` is a perfectly valid string in PHP, so it should not lead to any problems at *that* stage.

Comment: @vidarlo I was not highlighting a syntax problem. I was highlighting what you ended up doing in your answer ... `1` OR `2` will never equal `captcha` ...

Comment: @schroeder yep, but as I read your comment, it's a bit unclear. `$_POST["captcha"]` gets the value `1' || '2`... it doesn't enter as part of the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is a prime example of why you have to understand a system for you to be able to breach it. That's probably the point of this exercise as well; you need to know and notice security vulnerabilities.

If you don't know a particular one: you have to be able to read technical documentation, and figure out how to use a particular weakness. In this case the weakness has been pointed out specifically: the `==` comparator - with a link to how it works. From the description of how it works, you have to be able to figure out how to attack it.

`==` is hilighted as insecure in many, many places. `===` is the recomended comparator when user input is involved (or in general even).

How [`==` works is clearly documented, type for type](https://github.com/sentientmachine/php_equality_charts). Furthermore, you can test what is the expected value of the `$_SESSION["captcha"]` by visiting the page and submitting a valid captcha.

And as you know the language and source code, you can trivially test it on your own computer:

```
<?php
$captcha = "somestring";
$userinput = true;
if ($userinput == $captcha) 
   {
   print("== leads to truthy eval\n");
   }
if ($userinput === $captcha)
   {
   print("=== leads to truthy eval\n");
   }
?>
```

What do you expect that this snippet will output? `true` is *obviously* not equal to `"somestring"`.

That's the point of this excersize: hilight a common security vulnerability in PHP code, and teach you how it works, and what protections you can use against it.